# Grails maxRows/queryTimeout warning

Tags: grails

I seem to randomly get the warning below in my Grails 2.2.4 application.  It doesn't look like it is causing any issues, but it is still concerning.

I tried to prevent this warning by modifying my datasource properties in my `DataSource.groovy` file:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    properties {
        maxWait = 10000 // 10 seconds
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 1000 * 60 * 30 // 30 minutes
        numTestsPerEvictionRun = 3
        testOnBorrow = true
        testOnReturn = false
        testWhileIdle = false
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 1000 * 60 * 30 // 30 minutes
        validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
    }
}
```

And when that didn't work I tried to set the properties in my `BootStrap.groovy` file:

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    def ctx = Holders.getApplicationContext()
    def dataSource = ctx.dataSourceUnproxied

    println "configuring database connection pool"

    dataSource.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(1000 * 60 * 30)
    dataSource.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(1000 * 60 * 30)
    dataSource.setNumTestsPerEvictionRun(3)
    dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true)
    dataSource.setTestWhileIdle(false)
    dataSource.setTestOnReturn(false)
    dataSource.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1")
}
```

Neither attempt prevents the warning.  The author of [this](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Setting-dbcp-Properties-in-DataSource-groovy-tp3449959p3450481.html) post said he had success setting the properties directly in the tomcat config, but I need a more generic solution that will work from the command line and in other servers.

```
2013-09-25 15:07:51,027 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] WARN  jdbc.AbstractBatcher  - exception clearing maxRows/queryTimeout
java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement with address: "com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@13ed0db0: EXCEPTION: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after statement closed." is closed.
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.checkOpen(DelegatingStatement.java:137)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.getMaxRows(DelegatingStatement.java:237)
    at ace_2.DefsUploadController.upload(DefsUploadController.groovy:16)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Answer (score 1):

After connections to my MySQL database timed out I would see that exact exception as well.  I updated the DataSource configuration using the suggestion in the [Grails docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/conf.html) as a guideline and I have yet to see any exceptions from closed connections.

Here are my current settings:

```
    properties {
        initialSize=5
        maxActive=50
        minIdle=5
        maxIdle=25
        maxWait = 10000
        maxAge = 10 * 60000
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
        validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
        validationQueryTimeout = 3
        validationInterval = 15000
        testOnBorrow = true
        testWhileIdle = true
        testOnReturn = false
        jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState;StatementCache(max=200)"
        defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
    }
```